# Can i deploy to multi platform using phoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, cordova, windows-mobile

I am developing currently for IOS and Android SDK. So each time i have to do an app i have to develop for 2 separate platforms which take much time. Also i am planning to develop on BB , Windows Mobile etc. I came across Phonegap and i had some questions.

First suppose i am developing on MAC OS and Xcode 4 and i have install the required SDK for phonegap i create a project using the template and start coding in HTML5/CSS3. Once the project is completed how to import it to Android platform? Should i start to create a project and adding phonegap libraries and required jar and right away i can copy paste the HTML5/CSS3 from the www folder scripts into the required directory  /assets/www ? If that's the way it suppose to do then i will have to do the same for BB and Windows (of course on a Windows machine) we can do the same?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build.phonegap.com will build all the needed apps from your web content.